# VBA Excel To SqlServer

Tags: excel, sql-server-2005, vba

What is the best way to write VBA code to connect to SQL Server 2005 from Excel?

The users of the excel file might run XP, Vista, Win7 and I want to prevent driver installation as much as possible.

My understanding is that XP uses MDAC while Vista/Win7 uses DAC. Does that mean that a reference to MDAC 2.8 will not work on a Vista machine and the other way around?

Will my VBA code work on both if I don't add a reference and use late binding, e.g. CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")?

Comment: If you reference "ms activex data objects 2.8" then MDAC 2.8 must have been deployed on that xp machine. 
On vista the backwardly compatible MDAC 6 comes preinstalled, so you should be fine (It wont even allow 2.8 to be installed).
As you say, late binding with CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") will be version agnostic.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this using MS ADO 2.0 (the oldest version found on my workstation, added it as a reference). It's working on all the PC's I've tried it, you only have to enable macros (which wasn't good news at all)

```
Dim dbConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim connStr As String

'Recordset variables
Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
          "Data Source=MyServer\MyInstance;" & _
          "Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;" & _
          "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
          "Application Name=MyExcelFile"

Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
dbConnection.ConnectionString = connStr
dbConnection.Open

Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset
rsData.Open "SELECT field FROM table", dbConnection
Dim field as String
Do While Not rsData.EOF
    'this is where each row will be processed
    field = rsData.Fields(0).Value
    'do what's needed with field
    rsData.MoveNext
Loop
```