# Excel > Microsoft Query > SQL Server > Multiple Parameters

Tags: sql-server, excel

Im relatively new to sql server and excel/microsoft query,

I have a query like this

```
Select ...[data]...B1.b,B2.b,B3.b From TABLEA 
Inner join (
 SELECT ---[data]...sum(...) as b From TABLEB
 WHERE Date between [startdate] and [enddate]
) as B1
Inner join (
 SELECT ---[data]...sum(...) as b From TABLEB
 WHERE Date between [startdate-1week] and [enddate]
) as B2
Inner join (
 SELECT ---[data]...sum(...) as b From TABLEB
 WHERE Date between [startdate-2weeks] and [enddate]
) as B3
Where Date between [startdate] and [enddate]
```

It works, when i introduce the dates manually, but i need them to be "Dynamic" (introduced from excel) but, when I put the "?" (for parameters) on all the dates, it throws an error.

"Invalid Parameter Number"

:D How can i make this work, within excel?

Im using SQL Server and Microsoft Query Connection Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636246/vba-excel-to-sqlserver/2636302#2636302), then [this page](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=3687) to see examples of using parameters with ADO.

You should try naming parameters like this: @parameter1